# Changing order of integration over a non-tetrahedron region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I've tackled quite a few questions involving changing the order of integration over a general regions, however, for some reason, this one is troubling me. I am supposed to find three different iterated integrals to represent the given integral over the region specified, but after getting the first two, I can't seem to figure out how to structure the third. Consider the problem:

Using Fubini's theorem, write the three iterated version of the integral of the function $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ over the region bounded by $x, y, z\geq 0$, $x+2y-3\leq 1, z\leq x+y$ (you do not have to solve them).

I got:
$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_0^{4-2y}\int_{0}^{x+y} xyz ~dz ~dx ~dy$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_0^{2-x/2}\int_{0}^{x+y} xyz ~dz ~dy ~dx$$

Now, the last one cannot have $z$ as the first thing to be integrated, as we've already seen both of those possibilities. However, I am unsure how to write $z$ in terms of solely $x$ or $y$. Once I do that, how do I write (wlog) $x$ in terms of $x$ and $z$?

After a bit of digging, I found that $0\le z \le 4-y$, which may be useful. However, now I need to write $x$ in terms of $y,z$, which has proved to be a challenge. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Indeed, for fixed $y, z$, one of the boundary surfaces ("front" or "back" in the way I personally usually draw axes, but maybe "left" or "right" for you) is only piecewise smooth, and is made up of parts of two different planes.  This means you should expect to have to split your integral as a sum of two integrals.